# What does the commercial chemical composition notation "Percent dry, wet with water"mean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, terminology

I am not a chemist, I develop software. I'm hoping for a general explanation I can understand in order to assist me with a project I'm working on.

Customers viewing a product online such as peroxide see **97% (dry wt.), wet with 25% water**.

What does this mean? What would you expect the product to be in the form of? A powder, liquid/gel, solid in water? Any specific type of container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no general rule.
In your case (assuming you mean [this](https://us.vwr.com/store/catalog/product.jsp?product_id=9898342)) it is a solid. materials can have 25% and even more water and still be solids.

Comment: Yes, that is the type I was referring to. What type of packaging would this be shipped in? What I hope to do is create a web graphic that would incorporate the information, as well as any other useful shipping information.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it means that the product (a peroxide, explosive!) has been phlegmatized with 25 % water.  The product is a solid, of which 25 % are water.  The dry solid has been analyzed for peroxide content, and 97 % of the dry solid is benzoyl peroxide.

You would *think* it came in a plastic container because glass is basic and may leach ions that could catalyze decomposition of the product over time.  But that is just a hunch.